# Intent Help Xamarin C# Android?

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am not sure why this code is not working to be honest. I have been changing things around for  hours but I still cannot get it to work. Basically I have an app that I am using C# in Xamarin to make. I am trying to get the checkbox to go to the results page when it is checked and the button is pressed. Here is the code

```
Button button01 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button01);
            button01.Click += delegate {
            if (cb0.Checked) {
                new Intent (this, Songression.results);
```

please help.

Answer (score 2):

Please be precise what you want to do. If Songression.results is the data that you want to show on your results page then you have to add it to your intent like this :

```
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(YourResultActivity));
    intent.PutExtra("ResultData", Songression.results);
    StartActivity(intent);
```

And then you can get it in your result activity to display on your result page like this :

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        .....

        if (this.Intent.Extras.ContainsKey("ResultData"))
        {
            var resultData = this.Intent.Extras.Get("ResultData");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply creating a new Intent doesn't do anything.  You're not even saving a reference to it after you create it.  You should do something like this:

```
  var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ResultsActivity));
  StartActivity(intent);
```

Xamarin has an excellent [guide](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android_multiscreen/) on Multi Screen apps for Android - have you read it?

Comment: I just went and read it. Do I need to put something in my results activity?